# Filtering columns in Mysql database using php/html

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I would like to use check boxes to filter columns in a MYSQL database, that is viewed by a php file. As an example I will be using the w3 Left Join example for a table (As it almost exactly the same except different data). I have the basic HTML buttons, but I'm not entirely sure where I need to go from there.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p style="padding:none;">Filter: <span style="padding:none;font-size:10">Click box to remove option </span></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="CustName"/>Customer Name
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="ContName"/>Contact Name
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="CustCountry"/>Customer Country
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="OrderID"/>Order ID
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="OrderDate"/>Order Date

    <input  class="submit_display" type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Filter Customers" />
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    $output = 'Failed Connection'; 

  include 'output.html.php'; 

  exit(); 
}

$sql = " SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Customers.ContactName, Customers.Country, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate 
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName; ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "|CustomerName: " . $row["CustomerName"]."| OrderID: " . $row["OrderID"] . "  |<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

How would I be able to make the check boxes toggle their respective table column?

Comment: do you want to select the column from table or output only?

Comment: @Jah only the column from the table

Comment: either build your query to select only the columns you want, or modify your output to suppress the columns you DON'T. want.

Comment: @MarcB The reasoning on not doing that are there are a bunch of rows that have relevant data, but not all of it is relevant at once, so it'd make more sense to try to filter the rows you need at that particular time.

Answer (score 0):

mabe something like this?

```
<div>
    <form>

    <p style="padding:none;">Filter: <span style="padding:none;font-size:10">Click box to remove option </span></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="Customers.CustName"/>Customer Name
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="Customers.ContName"/>Contact Name
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="Customers.CustCountry"/>Customer Country
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="Orders.OrderID"/>Order ID
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value ="Orders.OrderDate"/>Order Date

    <input  class="submit_display" type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Filter Customers" />

    </form>
</div>

<?php
if(!empty($_GET['filter'])){
 $filter = implode(",",$_GET['filter']);
 $sql = "SELECT $filter";
    echo $sql;
}


    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this when I get to work on Friday, I'd try it know, but I cant Remote in or anything.